# If isset array - how in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I use tmdb_v3.php api with this code:

```
$movietrailer = $tmdb_V3->movieTrailer($idMovie);
```

In "pre" query I got this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 49017
    [quicktime] => Array
        (
        )

    [youtube] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I need an [php iffset]. If [youtube] contain value, echo "We have trailer". If no, echo "No trailer yet :(". I tried this but don't working:

```
if(isset($movietrailer['youtube']))
{ echo "We have trailer"; } else { echo "No trailer yet :("; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is *always* set. It just doesn't always have a value. Use `empty()` see if it has a value:

```
if(!empty($movietrailer['youtube'])) { 
    echo "We have trailer"; 
} else { 
    echo "No trailer yet :("; 
}
```